# Allow all attributes in $allowedposttags tags

Tags: escaping, iframe, allowedtags

I would like to use `$allowedposttags` to allow extra HTML tags during entry submission. Can I allow all attributes for a specific tag using `$allowedposttags`?

For example, the code below will allow iframe tags and the src, height, and width attributes in the iframe tags:

```
$allowedposttags['iframe'] = array(
    'src' => array(),
    'height' => array(),
    'width' => array()
);
```

How can I allow all attributes in this example, not just src, height, and width?

Comment: I'm starting to think that this isn't possible with just `$allowedposttags`. On [line 718 of wp-includes/kses.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L718), attributes that aren't present in `$allowedposttags` are skipped.

Comment: kses is designed to be a whitelist. There's no option to allow unlimited attributes without rewriting a lot of it. This is for safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to explicitly name all allowed attributes - just use:

```
$allowedposttags['iframe'] = array (
    'align'       => true,
    'frameborder' => true,
    'height'      => true,
    'width'       => true,
    'sandbox'     => true,
    'seamless'    => true,
    'scrolling'   => true,
    'srcdoc'      => true,
    'src'         => true,
    'class'       => true,
    'id'          => true,
    'style'       => true,
    'border'      => true,
);
```

If you can think of others let me know!

Comment: Skies the limit, I think. If we don't count custom attributes, [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element) has the definitive list, I believe.